# Searching backwards: implementing string.lastIndexOf(/REGEX/, offset) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, search

My overall goal is to select whole words following a click on a web page.

To do this, I need to find the first word boundary previous to the beginning of the current selection. Thanks to [@4castle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38935846/1927589), I have a regular expression that correctly identifies word boundaries. My current goal is to use this regular expression to search backwards in a string, imitating the way that `stringHaystack.lastIndexOf(stringNeedle, offset)` works.

My current solution is to reverse the part of the string before the `offset` point, then use `reverseString.search(regex)`, like this:

```
function searchBackwards (string, offset, regex) {
  string = string.substring(0, offset)
  var reverseString = ""
  var ii = string.length
  var backSet

  while (ii--) {
    reverseString += string[ii]
  }

  backSet = reverseString.search(regex)
  offset = backSet < 0 ? 0 : offset - backSet
  return offset
}
```

However, I feel that there must be a more elegant solution for this. Do you have any suggestions for improving this approach?

---

EDIT: Following @Wiktor Stribiżew's advice, I have changed my `searchBackwards` function to this:

```
function searchBackwards(string, offset, regex) {
  var adjust = 0
  var result
  string = string.substring(0, offset)

  while (result = regex.exec(string)) {
    offset = result.index
    adjust = result[0].length
  }

  return adjust ? offset + adjust : 0
}
```

In my tests on Chrome, it is about twice as fast as my original function.

---

Testable example: https://jsfiddle.net/77np9gp9/

Working code:

```
var selection = window.getSelection()
document.body.onmouseup = selectWholeWords

function selectWholeWords() {
  if (selection.rangeCount) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
    // RegExp to detect word boundaries but to allow ' and - in
    // the middle of words
    // ^['-]                    - match a single-quote or a hyphen
    //                            at the beginning
    // [\s!-/:-@\[-`\{-~'-]{2,} - match a whole range of non-word
    //                            characters pairs possibly 
    //                            including a ' or a -
    // [\s!-/:-@\[-`\{-~]       - match a whole range of non-word
    //                            characters on their own
    var regex = /^['-]|[\s!-/:-@\[-`\{-~'-]{2,}|[\s!-/:-@\[-`\{-~]/

    var container = range.startContainer
    var string = container.textContent 
    var offset = searchBackwards(string, range.startOffset)
    range.setStart(container, offset)     

    container = range.endContainer
    string = container.textContent
    offset = range.endOffset
    offset += string.substring(offset).search(regex)
    if (offset < 0) {
      offset = string.length
    }
    range.setEnd(container, offset)

    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range)
  }

  function searchBackwards (string, offset) {
    string = string.substring(0, offset)
    var reverseString = ""
    var ii = string.length
    var backSet

    while (ii--) {
      reverseString += string[ii]
    }

    backSet = reverseString.search(regex)
    offset = backSet < 0 ? 0 : offset - backSet
    return offset
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to find the last match, collect all and access the last item.

Comment: What should happen when matches overlap?

Comment: `pattern(?!.*?pattern)`

Comment: @PaulS. Your technique is cool, but it does seem to work when `pattern` is replaced with `[\s!-\/:-@\[-`\{-~]{2,}|[\s!-&\(-,.-\/:-@\[-`\{-~]` https://regex101.com/r/gO9jL0/1 – the first match for the pattern is selected, not the last.

Comment: @JamesNewton The OR in the pattern splits the RegExp, it would require a group to work as a single thing, e.g. non-capture group `(?:pattern)(?!.*(?:pattern))`

Comment: @PaulS In my tests on Chrome, using your technique is slower than finding all matches and choosing the last one. For a string of 200 characters, it is an order of magnitude slower; for a string of 20,000 characters, it is about half the speed. I am guessing that finding-all-matches runs through the string only once, while your lookahead technique runs ahead to the next match each time, and then starts over from the next character after the earlier match.